# Calculate sum of dynamically added values with vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

I am dynamically adding new row with selects and inputs in table if option is selected in first column of last row.

It looks like this https://jsfiddle.net/zgykgery/ so when you select 'Service' new row is added and total price of that row is calculated taking service price, default 10% discount and amount.

I am getting service price a bit clumsy with 
`:value="item.id+'|'+item.price"`
so I have filter to take it from value.
But it works and now I don't know how I can loop through all rows and sum price of service without dicount, sum discount and then full price with servce price and discount.

I know I should use computed properties or watcher but don't know how.

How can I compute sum of those values in table and display them in smaller table below?

***Update***

I am new in vue and didn't use computed properties so this is what I tried but without success:

```js
var Main = {
  data() {
    return {
      rows_top: [{
        service: '',
        position: '',
        visit: '',
        amount: '',
        discount: 10
      }],
      services: [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'Service1',
          price: 100
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Service2',
          price: 200
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'Service3',
          price: 300
        },
      ],
      total_discount: 0,
      total_full_price: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addRow(row, index) {
      // console.log(row)
      if (this.rows_top[this.rows_top.length - 1].service !== '') {
        this.rows_top.push({
          service: '',
          position: '',
          visit: '',
          amount: '',
          discount: 10
        })
      }
    },
    deleteRow(index) {
      this.rows_top.splice(index, 1)
    }
  },
  computed: {
    total_price: () => {
      if (this.rows_top) {
        return this.rows_top.map((r) => {
          return r.amount * this.$options.filters.after_line(r.service)
        })
      }
    }
  },
  filters: {
    after_line: (value) => {
      if (!value) return ''
      let after = value.split('|')
      return after.pop()
    }
  }
}
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.0.11/lib/theme-chalk/index.css");
table {
  border-collapse: collapse
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f9f9f9
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.2.0/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template>
  <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Service</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Visit</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Discount %</th>
      <th>Full price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(row, index) in rows_top">
      <td>
        <el-select placeholder="Select" filterable="filterable" @change="addRow(row, index)" v-model="row.service">
          <el-option v-for="item in services" :key="item.id" :label="item.name" :value="item.id+'|'+item.price"></el-option>
        </el-select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <el-select placeholder="Select" v-model="row.position" multiple="multiple" filterable="filterable" allow-create="allow-create" @change="checkNumber(result, index)"></el-select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <el-select placeholder="Select" v-model="row.visit" allow-create="allow-create" filterable="filterable">
          <el-option v-for="i in 10" :key="i" :label="i" :value="i"></el-option>
        </el-select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <el-select placeholder="Select" v-model="row.amount" allow-create="allow-create" filterable="filterable">
          <el-option v-for="i in 30" :key="i" :label="i" :value="i"></el-option>
        </el-select>
      </td>
      <td>{{ row.service | after_line }}</td>
      <td>
        <el-input v-model="row.discount"></el-input>
      </td>
      <td><span v-if="row.service && row.amount">{{ ($options.filters.after_line(row.service) * row.amount - (($options.filters.after_line(row.service) * row.amount) / 100) * row.discount).toFixed(2) }}</span><span v-else-if="row.service">{{ ($options.filters.after_line(row.service) - ($options.filters.after_line(row.service) / 100) * row.discount).toFixed(2) }}</span>
        <el-button v-if="row.service" icon="el-icon-delete" size="mini" @click="deleteRow(index)" class="push-right"></el-button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table><br/>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Total price</td>
    <td>{{ total_price }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Total discount</td>
    <td>{{ total_discount }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Total full price</td>
    <td>{{ total_full_price }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</template>
</div>
```

Here is also updated fiddle and total price is still empty on change https://jsfiddle.net/zgykgery/21/

Comment: Use a [computed](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html). Just write the function that does the calculation and make that the computed.

Comment: @RoyJ thanks, yes I assumed computed should be used but I am new in that. Can you check am I on right track in updated question? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please put a Minimal, COMPLETE, Verifiable, Example **IN THE QUESTION ITSELF**. Just linking to a jsfiddle is not enough. Just putting a few lines in your question is not enough.

Comment: @gman ok, I added full code to question

Answer (score 1):

As @Roy J said, just use a computed function to get you the values of your calculation, knowing that it will automatically change when the data from `item` changes

**EDIT**: a simple `method` is more designed in the case when you use a `v-for` loop

```
methods: {
    priceID (item) {
        return item.id + '|' + item.price
    }
}
```

And you would use it simply like that in your Vue

```
<tr v-for="(row, index) in rows_top">
  <td>
    <el-select placeholder="Select" filterable="filterable" @change="addRow(row, index)" v-model="row.service">
      <el-option v-for="item in services" :key="item.id" :label="item.name" :value="priceID(item)"></el-option>
    </el-select>
  </td>
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks but with this I am getting that item is undefined. Can you check updated question?

Comment: Didn't see the item variable come from your v-for loop, you then just have to pass a parameter to the function (i.e priceID) which will be `item`. But as you're using a v-for loop to get `item`, there's no point using a `computed` so you can fallback to a standard function in `methods`. Updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks for that but I don't know if you understand what I need. I need sum of values in rows that are dynamically added with that select. Like described in question. Is this method that you proposed helping me get that in some way?

Comment: Ofc, you can pass whatever you need to count your rows to the function !